# How to convert a Julia Bool Array to Fortran Logical Array

Tags: julia

How can I convert a Julia Int/Bool Array/Vector to a Fortran LOGICAL array for use within Julia's ccall?

I tried passing it as Array{Bool} in https://gist.github.com/axsk/28f297e2207365a7f4e8/, but the code is not working correctly and I am quite confident the problem is the Bool-Logical conversion.

Comment: in http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#bits-types is written that even the bool type has 8 bits. probably this is the problem, but how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know too much about calling Fortran code, but according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Internal-representation-of-LOGICAL-variables.html)

> The Fortran standard does not specify how variables of LOGICAL type
>   are represented, beyond requiring that LOGICAL variables of default
>   kind have the same storage size as default INTEGER and REAL variables.
>   The GNU Fortran internal representation is as follows.
>
> A LOGICAL(KIND=N) variable is represented as an INTEGER(KIND=N)
>   variable, however, with only two permissible values: 1 for .TRUE. and
>   0 for .FALSE.. Any other integer value results in undefined behavior.

So I'd do something like the following

```
julia_array = rand(Bool, 1:10)
fort_array  = Int[x?1:0 for x in julia_array]
```

Then use `fort_array` as the input. Which Fortran compiler are you using?

EDIT: It turns out the Julia developers already define a type that will work with the linked BLAS/LAPACK, `Base.BLAS.BlasInt`, that will use the correct `Int` variant for the system.

Comment: I'm not compiling the Fortran code myself but am using the LAPACK Fortran library which is shipped with Julia. But thanks so far, I will try that when back at home.

Comment: If it follows that convention I think you'll be in luck. If that doesn't work, next thing to try would be making the array type CInt

Comment: So it looks like this solved your problem? (going by https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/Bn1c5npwGzo)

Comment: yep, it did. i thought i tried it before and it didn't work, but probably i messed up something else there too as its working now.
thanks a lot!

Comment: well. it was not that easy, as the tests failed on different machines (linux wanted Cint, windows Int)

Answer (score 0):

As iaindunning posted before, Fortran represents `Logical` variables as `Integers`.
Unfortunately the representation of the type `Integer` varies from platform to platform.
While I had success using `Int` on Windows and `Cint` on Linux/MacOS, in the end I used `BlasInt`, which adopts depending on the platform.

Comment: It would seem to be against SO etiquette to accept my answer, then switch to your own later, mostly using info from my own. I think it would have been more appropriate to update my answer with the final piece of the puzzle (BlasInt). Anyway, glad it worked.

Comment: sorry, wasn't sure about this myself. here we go :)